# Lazy loading on scrolling drop down options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

I am working on MEAN stack application in which I am defining a drop down using following customize directive. This drop down shows available variables from an array(around 70K options).

```
.directive('inputDropdown', function($parse) {

    var template = 
        '<input class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-focus="setDirectiveList()" ng-blur="removeDirectiveList()">' +
        '<div class="dropdown dropdown1" input-dropdown="increaseLimit()" ng-init="limit=20;" ng-click="setDirectiveList()">' + 
            '<div class="form-control" ng-repeat="value in selectedList | filter:ngModel | limitTo:limit">' +
                '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            list: '=',
            onSelect: '&',
            disabled:'=ngDisabled'
        },
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,mapController) {
            element.addClass('input-dropdown');

            var handler = $parse(attrs.inputDropdown);
            element.scroll(function (evt) {
              var scrollTop    = element[0].scrollTop,
                  scrollHeight = element[0].scrollHeight,
                  offsetHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
              if (scrollTop === (scrollHeight - offsetHeight)) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                  handler($scope);
                });
              }
            });

            if(scope.$parent.setDirty)
            {
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            }
            scope.select = function(e, value) {
                scope.ngModel = value;
                // scope.onSelect({$event: e, value: value});
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            };
            scope.setDirectiveList = function() {
                // debugger;
                scope.selectedList = scope.list;//scope.$parent.variables;
            }
            scope.removeDirectiveList = function() {
                scope.selectedList = [];
            }
        }
    };
})
```

What I am trying to do is using `limitTo` option, increasing the the display variables count by some value when the scroll bar of drop down hits bottom. The `increaseLimit` function is defined in my controller as:

```
 $scope.increaseLimit = function () {
        if ($scope.limit < $scope.variables.length) {
          $scope.limit += 20;
        }
 };
```

where `$scope.variables` contains 70K entries. I am not sure whether the I am adding `increaseLimit` to correct `div` or scrolling function is wrong.

I want to achieve [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/S2x6L8wNjXD8g00WVsJz?p=preview) type of loading in my drop down. How to add this in my customize directive `input-dropdown`. I tried but no success.

Please Help.